# How can I create an indented and hanging-indented list with enumitem

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm using `enumitem` v3.2 (latest on MikTeX), and want to create a list that looks like this:

```
Some text describing my list:
    **Item 1**: some text that eventually wraps
         and hangs onto line two
    **Item 2**: some text that eventually wraps
         and hangs onto line two
Some more text
```

I've managed to create the following instead, using `[labelindent=2em,itemindent=3em]`:

```
Some text describing my list:
        **Item 1**: some text that eventually wraps
     onto line two
        **Item 2**: some text that eventually wraps
     onto line two
Some more text
```

I've been trying to make sense of the parameters in the `enumitem` documentation, but I seem not to be having any luck.  When I tried making `labelindent` negative, that had no effect.  I'm sure there's some simple way to achieve this, so I appeal to the wisdom of the crowds...

**EDIT**: Minimum (non-)working example follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{compactdesc}{description}{3}
\setlist[compactdesc]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \emph{Example text}
  \begin{compactdesc}[labelindent=2em,itemindent=3em]\raggedright
  \item[Loren ipsum:] dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim
    ultricies.
  \item[Ut aliquet:] mi vel lacus dictum iaculis. Aenean vestibulum
    pharetra magna, sit amet venenatis velit posuere ut.
  \item[Fusce viverra:] commodo erat, quis feugiat purus tempor sit
    amet. Nulla tincidunt erat nec diam porta accumsan.
  \end{compactdesc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used? A simple example like this works are you would expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `leftmargin` rather than the `itemindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{compactdesc}{description}{3}
\setlist[compactdesc]{topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \emph{Example text}
  \begin{compactdesc}[leftmargin=5em,labelindent=3em]\raggedright
  \item[Loren ipsum:] dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Duis tincidunt mi ut purus varius aliquet posuere enim
    ultricies.
  \item[Ut aliquet:] mi vel lacus dictum iaculis. Aenean vestibulum
    pharetra magna, sit amet venenatis velit posuere ut.
  \item[Fusce viverra:] commodo erat, quis feugiat purus tempor sit
    amet. Nulla tincidunt erat nec diam porta accumsan.
  \end{compactdesc}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as intended.  (I'd love to see a better diagram of which direction--left or right--each of the five horizontal parameters pushes the text around.  As the `enumitem` package author notes, he intends to improve the existing figures in a future release :-p)